# Yom Tov Sheni after Moshiach

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz, messiah

Will there be a Yom Tov Sheni after Moshiach comes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After moshiach comes, all Jews will live in Eretz Yisrael, either in its original form, or in a different form described by Yechezkel toward the end of his prophesies. Either way, there will be no need for yom tov sheni.
Even if, during yemos hamashiach, one were to be in Chutz La'aretz, I doubt they would need to observe yom tov sheni, as they would be considered residents of Eretz Yisrael, who always observe one day regardless of their temporary location.

EDIT: It is true, as SimchasTorah suggests in the comments, that the Chasam Sofer, who in general took a more mystical, less technical approach to yom tov sheni, believes that after Mashiach comes, we will celebrate yom tov sheni to remind us of the long galus we were in previously. It can be found here: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21254&st=&pgnum=131&hilite= (paragraph starting "l'maan")

Comment: Per Rambam (Hil. Kiddush Hachodesh 5:9ff), though, it doesn't really depend on Eretz Yisrael vs. Chutz Laaretz, but rather on closeness to Jerusalem and whether the place was inhabited by Jews in the times of the second Beis Hamikdash. Arguably, then, since Eretz Yisrael in Moshiach's times will be considerably larger than in earlier eras, it may well include areas where Yom Tov Sheni needs to be observed. (Unless the Sanhedrin decides that with modern communications technology it is no longer needed.)

Comment: I was told that the CHasam Sofer says there will be Yom tov Sheini in memorial of golus if anyone can find it I would appreciate it

Comment: @Alex, point well made. However, even if Yom Tov sheni will be observed in Chutz La'aretz after Mashiach, I don't think Eretz Yisrael itself will expand to such a size that the shluchei beis din will not have been able to travel its expanse in two weeks time.

Comment: @jake – Maybe the rabbis will decide to permit notifications of New Month via the Internets!?

Answer (score 3):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe says that [it is possible](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/from-exile-to-redemption-2/04.htm#t81) that Yom Tov Sheni will continue to be celebrated because it has been done for so many generations. Even though the calendar will be replaced with the Sanhedrin declaring the month based on testimoney, it will still not be technically necessary to keep two days anywhere, as everyone will know right away when the new month started.

Comment: There already is technically no need for it. More importantly, did anyone think it would be impossible? In the future the Sanhedrin could establish Yom Tov Shlishi (and Revi'i) if they wanted to. I don't see what this answer adds.

Comment: @DoubleAA, it adds a second reason, other than the reason quoted by the Chasam Sofer. I didn't think a comment or an answer edit was quite appropriate, so I added the point as a second answer. I also clarified now that the technicality will be different than it is now.

Comment: How will the Jews in India know about Rosh Chodesh Tishrei right away?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Isn't the point of Moshiach that all the Jews will return to Eretz Yisroel? This way Yovel will be able to be observed. Anyway, "instantly" can mean after Yom Tov, it could mean non-Jews will carry the message, and the second day Rosh Hashana is a completely different issue anyway - it has nothing to do with sfeika d'yoma in the same sense as Pesach and Succos.

Comment: I don't know if that is _the point_ of Mashiach, and you certainly don't need every Jew in Israel to observe Yovel. Aside from satellite communication, I'm not sure how it will be any different than back in the day when some places did have a doubt sometimes.

Comment: @DoubleAA, why exclude satellite communication from the equation?

Comment: because that's no different than today. As in, now too there is no doubt anywhere but there's a gezera in case somehow someone is stuck that he should know how to do it.