# Megilas Eicha in Lasid Lavo

Tags: halacha-theory, messiah, beis-hamikdash, tisha-bav, latid-lavo-future

Are there any sources that discuss whether we will Lain Megilas Eicha in Lasid Lavo? Aside from knowing that Tisha B'Av will be a Moed in Yemos HaMashiach, do we have any other basis of knowing what it will look like?

Comment: Why do you think there's any reason we would read it then? Please [edit] to clarify

Comment: @DoubleAA There is an opinion that says that even after the existence of the 3rd Temple, people living far away from Israel would still need to observe 2nd day Yom Tov *zecher lechurban*. Perhaps, reading Eicha would be for the same reason.

Comment: @DanF Do you have a source for that Deah?

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps as a Zechira...the fact that we would be living within Geula Shleima doesn't remove the Churban of Bayis Rishon and Sheini, the history is still there.

Comment: I think I asked a related M.Y. question that cites this opinion. B"N, I'll see if I can find it. Found it! See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/33300/5275

Comment: A rabbi once told me Eicha is hard to find on klaf because sofrim are reluctant to spend time on a book which will imy"h be batul soon.

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi That's assuming that it would be. Regardless, it seems like a somewhat funny reason. For a while Haftarot were written on klaf, and if I understand that idea, it was the "original" haftarot. During this time of year, there were designated haftarot for Va'etchanan - at least Netzavim, not the 7 Denechamta that we have, today. So, essentially, all those klaf haftarot are "defunct".

Comment: @DanF In our beis medrash we read haftora from klaf. but they are sifrei neviim. No one writes klaf with only the haftoras and no other passages.?

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi You are correct. See my recent question, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83998/5275, for info & historical background behind my comment about klaf, and my other question, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84520/5275 about the haftarah list.

Answer (score 2):

[**Yerushalmi, Megilah 1:5**](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%90) ([**7a**](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14138&st=&pgnum=468)):

> ר' יוחנן ורשב"ל ר' יוחנן אמר הנביאים והכתובים עתידין ליבטל וחמשה סיפרי תורה אינן עתידין ליבטל מה טעמא (דברים ה) קול גדול ולא יסף רשב"ל אמר אף מגילת אסתר והלכות אינן עתידין ליבטל נאמר כאן קול גדול ולא יסף ונאמר להלן (אסתר ט) וזכרם לא יסוף מזרעם הלכות (חבקוק ג) הליכות עולם לו
>
> - Rabbi Yochanan said that all the Nevim and Kesuvim will be canceled [out of use] in the future, but not the Chumash because it is *a great voice which will not cease* (Dev. 5).
> - Reish Lakish says that the scroll of Esther will also remain in use, along with its laws since it also says *the memory will not cease from their seed* (Esther 9) and *they are his eternal laws* (Chavakuk 3).

**[Mishneh Torah, Scroll of Esther and Hanukkah 2:](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Scroll_of_Esther_and_Hanukkah.2.18?lang=bi)**

> כָּל סִפְרֵי הַנְּבִיאִים וְכָל הַכְּתוּבִים עֲתִידִין לִבָּטֵל לִימוֹת הַמָּשִׁיחַ חוּץ מִמְּגִלַּת אֶסְתֵּר וַהֲרֵי הִיא קַיֶּמֶת כַּחֲמִשָּׁה חֻמְּשֵׁי תּוֹרָה וְכַהֲלָכוֹת שֶׁל תּוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה שֶׁאֵינָן בְּטֵלִין לְעוֹלָם. וְאַף עַל פִּי שֶׁכָּל זִכְרוֹן הַצָּרוֹת יְבֻטַּל שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה סה טז) "כִּי נִשְׁכְּחוּ הַצָּרוֹת הָרִאשׁוֹנוֹת וְכִי נִסְתְּרוּ מֵעֵינִי". יְמֵי הַפּוּרִים לֹא יִבָּטְלוּ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (אסתר ט כח) "וִימֵי הַפּוּרִים הָאֵלֶּה לֹא יַעַבְרוּ מִתּוֹךְ הַיְּהוּדִים וְזִכְרָם לֹא יָסוּף מִזַּרְעָם":
>
> All Prophetic Books and the Sacred Writings will cease [to be recited in public] during the messianic era except the Book of Esther. It will continue to exist just as the Five Books of the Torah and the laws of the Oral Torah that will never cease. Although ancient troubles will be remembered no longer, as it is written: "The troubles of the past are forgotten and hidden from my eyes" (Isaiah 65:16), the days of Purim will not be abolished, as it is written: "These days of Purim shall never be repealed among the Jews, and the memory of them shall never cease from their descendants" (Esther 9:28).

The Raavad points out specifically, all other books will not be read in public, but if any laws are learned from them, they will not be canceled.

> כל ספרי הנביאים וכו'. א''א לא יבטל דבר מכל הספרים שאין ספר שאין בו למוד. אבל כך אמרו אפילו יבטלו שאר ספרים מלקרות בהם מגילה לא תבטל מלקרותה בצבור, עכ''ל:

Lechem Mishneh commments that they will only seldom be read.

> אלא אע''פ שאין קוראים בהם בכל שעה אלא לשום עת רחוק מ''מ במגילת אסתר קורין

**[Radbaz 2:666:](https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRadbaz_Volume_2.666.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)**

> כי כל ספרי הנביאים והכתובים נכתבו ונסדרו על הצרות שעברו בזמנם או על הצרות אשר עתידים להיות וכל דברים אלו ישתכחו ויתבטלו
>
> All of nevim and kesuvim were written and arranged on account of the calamities that were occurring during the time of writing or about prophesied calamities. However, in the future all these things will have passed and be forgotten and be canceled.

This seems to suggest that we will not read Megilas Eicha in Lasid Lavo.

Comment: From the Raavad it basically comes out that Esther is not necessarily special.  For all of the books, including Esther, any laws learned from them are not canceled.  But it turns out that one of the laws we learn from Esther is that we have to read it, so we'll read it.

Answer (score -1):

[Rabbi David Shlomo Eibeschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Solomon_Eibenschutz) (1755-1813) was the author of many kabalistic and Talmudical works; including “Levushei Sera” (a commentary on Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayim, and Yoreh De'ah), and Arvei Nachal” (on the Pentateuch, and sermons).

A lesser known work, “[Masos Kol Ha-Mitaablim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A5)” (The Joy of All the Mourners), was written in 5543 (1783 CE). It is a dual kabbalistic homiletical commentary on the Book of Eichah, which contains two parts, happiness and mourning. "Masos", is the path of joy and consolation, and the second, "Ha-Mitaablim", is the path of grief and sigh.

The path of “joy and consolation” offers an alternate understanding of the verses, which speaks of the future redemption.

The work remained in manuscript form for some two hundred years, until the year 5749, when it was printed in Jerusalem. It is also found in the Otzar HaChochmah computer program.

It is quite possible that "le'asid lavo", the Book of Eichah will be read (privately?) with new-found insight and commentary, reflective of the consolations hidden in the text.