# Are any communities reciting Rambam's list of Haftarot for most of the book of Devarim?

Tags: rambam, haftarah, deuteronomy

Thanks to DoubleAA for introducing me to [this list of Haftarot](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2700.htm) from Ramba"m's Sefer Ahava; Seder Hatefillah #61 (See near bottom of the linked page.)

Most congregations have replaced the 7 haftarot from Devarim to Ha'azinu with others which focus on 1 (of the 3) *Puranuta* ("rebukes" - for Shabbat Devarim / Chazon) followed by 7 *nechemta* (consolation) from Va'etchanan to Netzavim (or Netzavim Vayelech) and a different haftara for Shabbat Shuva and a different one for "Ha'azinu" (on years when that is not Shabbat Shuva.)

Is there any community or group of people that still follows Rambam's list? If so, whom?

Comment: I'm betting on the Yemenites.

Comment: @loe nah, italians or romaniotes is the better bet

Comment: To clarify: You're asking about the list in [#61](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2700.htm#61), and not the one further down in  [#63](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/2700.htm#63), right? (I'm checking because you don't explicitly mention the latter section in your question.)